# pip command by default using python 3...how to change it to python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12 and after I upgraded my OS I can no longer install packages for python 3 using pip. Before I used to use pip for python2 and pip3 for python 3 as I have both versions of Python. But now I can no longer use pip to install libraries for python2.

Can anyone help me how can I change my default pip installer to python2? So that I can just use pip install in order to install for python 2.

For your information - when I only type python on terminal it says my default is python 2.7.

Comment: Yes use `pip2` for python2

Comment: pip2 command is not working for my mac....how can i enable it?

Comment: Try this command `python -m pip install <lib>` or `python3 -m pip install <lib>` for python 3

Answer (score 3):

on running

```
which pip
```

I got `/usr/local/bin/pip`
Which meant it was pointing to pip2

To change default pip to pip3, run

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 1):

install pip for Python2.7 with easy_install:

**sudo easy_install-2.7 pip**

now you can use pip for the same specific version of Python:

**sudo pip2.7 install BeautifulSoup**